# dbus Variant: How to preserve boolean datatype in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, boolean, dbus, variant

I've been experimenting with dbus lately. But I can't seem to get my dbus Service to guess the correct datatypes for boolean values. Consider the following example:

```
import gtk
import dbus
import dbus.service
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

class Service(dbus.service.Object):

  def __init__(self):
    bus_name = dbus.service.BusName("org.foo.bar", bus = dbus.SessionBus())
    dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, "/org/foo/bar")


  @dbus.service.method("org.foo.bar", in_signature = "a{sa{sv}}",
    out_signature = "a{sa{sv}}")
  def perform(self, data):   
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
  DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default = True)
  s = Service()
  gtk.main()
```

This piece of code creates a dbus service that provides the perform method which accepts one parameter that is a dictionary which maps from strings to other dictionaries, which in turn map strings to variants. I have chosen this format because of the format my dictionaries are in:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "type": ("tuple", "value")
  },
  "key2": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 23
  },
  "test": {
    "true-property": True,
    "false-property": False
  }
}
```

When I pass this dictionary through my service, the boolean values are converted to integers. In my eyes, the check should not be that difficult. Consider this (`value` is the variable to be converted to a dbus type):

```
if isinstance(value, bool):
  return dbus.Boolean(value)
```

If this check is done before checking for `isinstance(value, int)` then there would be no problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which part you're having difficulty with. The types can easily be cast from one form to another, as you show in your example `dbus.Boolean(val)`. You can also use `isinstance(value, dbus.Boolean)` to test if the value is a dbus boolean, not an integer.

The Python native types are converted into `dbus` types in order to enable communicate between DBus clients and services written in any language.  So any data sent to / received from a DBus service will consist of `dbus.*` data types.

```
def perform(self, data):
    for key in ['true-property', 'false-property']:
        val = data['test'][key]
        newval = bool(val)

        print '%s type: %s' % (key, type(val))
        print 'is dbus.Boolean: %s' % isinstance(val, dbus.Boolean)
        print 'Python:', newval
        print '  Dbus:', dbus.Boolean(newval)
    return data
```

Output:

```
true-property type: <type 'dbus.Boolean'>
is dbus.Boolean: True
Python: True
  Dbus: 1
false-property type: <type 'dbus.Boolean'>
is dbus.Boolean: True
Python: False
  Dbus: 0
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to the correct solution. I am converting the dbus types into yet another format. This conversion used the check `isinstance(value, bool)`. This should work, but `dbus.Boolean` inherits from `int`, since `bool` [cannot be subclassed](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.Boolean-class.html). I simply needed to adapt the conversion to check for a `dbus.Boolean` instance.